# Как при нажатии на одну кнопку активировать обе?

Tags: php, javascript, form, формы

Здравствуйте. На сайте есть два поля и две кнопки. Это выглядит так:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST;

echo '<form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Введите ссылку">
        <input type="submit" name="do_search" value="Найти">
        </form>';
if( isset($data['do_search']) ) {
    // действия
}

echo '<form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="url2" placeholder="Введите ссылку">
        <input type="submit" name="do_search2" value="Найти">
        </form>';

if( isset($data['do_search2']) ) {
    // действия
}

?>
```

Всё работает, но действия выполняются по отдельности. Нужно, чтобы человек ввёл по ссылке в каждое поле и нажал на первую кнопку, а эта кнопка стриггерила бы вторую кнопку. И в итоге должны показаться результаты двух полей (do_search и do_search2), но при этом нажата одна кнопка. Возможно, нужно задействовать JS. Кто знает решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предпочтительный вариант - объединить два формы в одну:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST;

echo '<form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Введите ссылку">
        <input type="submit" name="do_search" value="Найти">';
if( isset($data['url']) ) {
    // действия
}

echo '<input type="text" name="url2" placeholder="Введите ссылку">
        <input type="submit" name="do_search2" value="Найти">
        </form>';

if( isset($data['url2']) ) {
    // действия
}

?>
```

Более сложный способ - отправлять обе формы аяксом, подставляя полученные данные в нужные места.